# AngularJS preserve tab on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, coffeescript

I have the following code (coffee script):

```
window.AddressGridController = [ 
  "$scope", "$rootScope", "$http"
  ($scope, $rootScope, $http) ->
    init = window.angularInit
    $scope.countryNames = init.countryNames
    $scope.addressBook = init.addressBook
    $scope.addressBook.unshift "__add_address"
    $scope.currentPage = 0
    $scope.pageSize = 8
    $scope.totalPages = Math.ceil($scope.addressBook.length / $scope.pageSize)
    $scope.isSelected = (ai) ->  $rootScope.selAddress is ai.address._id
    $scope.setSelected = (ai, toggle) ->
      if toggle and $rootScope.selAddress is ai.address._id
        $rootScope.setAddress(null)
      else
        $rootScope.setAddress(ai)
    if init.cart
      addrId = if init.cart.warehousePickup then "WAREHOUSE" else init.cart.address
      for addrInfo,index in init.addressBook
        if addrInfo.address and addrInfo.address._id is addrId
          $scope.setSelected addrInfo
    $scope.showForm = ->
      $rootScope.setAddress(null)
      $rootScope.$broadcast "new-address"
    $scope.$on "address-update",  (e, index, ai) -> 
      index = if index is -1 then $scope.addressBook.length else (index + 1)  
      $scope.addressBook[index] = ai
      if $rootScope.selAddress is ai.address._id
        $rootScope.setAddress(ai)
    $scope.editAddress = (ai) -> $rootScope.$broadcast "edit-address", ai
    $scope.deleteAddress = (ai) -> 
      if window.confirm("Do you really want to delete this address ? [You can't undo it]")
        postData = _csrf: window.angularInit._csrf
        $http.post("/address/user/delete/#{ai.address._id}", postData)
          .success (data) ->
            $rootScope.setAddress(null)  
            ii = $scope.addressBook.indexOf ai
            $scope.addressBook.splice ii, 1
          .error (data) -> alert "Server error " + ((data.error and data.error.message) or data)
  ]
```

[image]

the problem is that when the user refreshes the page, the selected address is hidden on page 2.

how do i save the position correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To save the tab across refreshes, you can set it as a query parameter in the route, eg. `http://www.example.com/index.html?page=2&selectedIndex=4`. The `page=2&selectedIndex=4` (everything after the '?') is the query string, and can be used as parameters in your app. The advantage this has over using local storage is the URL can then be shared with others, or you can bookmark it, or whatever.

To set the query parameters:

```
function onClick(itemIndex) {
    // Add the selected index to the query parameters
    $location.search({page: $scope.currentPage, selectedIndex: itemIndex});
}
```

Now your URL will be something like `http://localhost/my-route?selectedIndex=2`, and then in your app initialization you just need to read the $routeParams:

```
var page = $routeParams.page;
var selectedIndex = $routeParams.selectedIndex;
```

You'll also need to change the reloadOnSearch property to false, or else the page will refresh when you set the route parameter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

```
$routeProvider
.when('/my-route', {
        title: 'My Title',
        templateUrl: 'my-template.html',
        controller:  'MyCtrl',
        reloadOnSearch: false  // Make sure the page doesn't reload when $location.search is called
      }).
```

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider
for more details.